# Illustrator CC 2015 text and color profiles

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there any way in Illustrator CC 2015 to save a text and color profile? I want to apply the saved presets on the marked text of my document by just clicking an option.

For example, I want to use Myriad pro 16px, #ccc for my titles and Verdana 14px for my main text.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator's **[Character and Paragraph Styles](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/character-paragraph-styles.html)** are designed to save formatting of text and then have the ability to reapply that same formatting to other text.

It is also possible to move Character and Paragraph styles, all or merely one, to another document in order to use the Styles there.